# Executar uma migration específica no Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, migrations

Estou com a necessidade de executar apenas uma `migration` dentro do meu sistema `laravel`, para não afetar o restante do mesmo.

Trecho da migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('body')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('date');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Já tentei alguns procedimentos como os descritos [aqui](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/ho-to-execute-a-specific-migration#reply-188079) mas todos sem sucesso. Sempre retornando:

> Nothing to migrate.

Obs: O sistema foi atualizado e há alterações a serem migradas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depois de muita pesquisa e bater cabeça cheguei a uma solução para executar uma ou várias migrations especificas.

Primeiro é necessário criar uma pasta temporária que será usada para executar as migrations que você necessita, no meu caso chamei de **temp** e criei no caminho:

```
PROJECT_FOLDER/database/migrations
```

Após isso é necessário copiar as migrations que deseja para dentro da pasta temporária que acabou de criar. Em seguida basta executar o comando a seguir na pasta raiz do seu projeto, que ele se encarregará de executá-las.

```
PROJECT_FOLDER> php artisan migrate --path="databse/migrations/temp"
```

***Exemplo de uso***

Pastas:

```
PROJECT_FOLDER -
  -database
     -migrations
        migration_01.php
        migration_02.php
```

Executando processos(Linux) para executar apenas a `migration_02.php`:

```
PROJECT_FOLDER> mkdir database/migations/temp
PROJECT_FOLDER> cp -rf database/migations/migration_02.php database/migations/temp
PROJECT_FOLDER> php artisan migrate --path="database/migrations/temp"
```

OBS: Lembrando que serão migrados todos os arquivos que estão dentro da sua pasta temporária.

Answer (score 2):

Se você tem acesso ao banco de dados, basta acessar a tabela `migrations` e deletar o registro da tabela. Então, execute o comando `php artisan migrate` novamente.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você executa o comando `php artisan:migrate` o Laravel lê os seus arquivos dentro da pasta `database/migrations` e então carrega as classes e cria registro na tabela `migrations` caso o arquivo ainda não tenha sido registado. Com isso, se você alterou uma migration que já foi executada, é necessário o comando `php artisan migrate:rollback`, para desfazer as migrations.

Você pode ler mais sobre neste link: ***[Database: Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#rolling-back-migrations)***

Comment: Ja realizei todos esses passos e sem sucesso, acredito que será necessário uma solução alternativa a isso